# Rancher desktop mounting volume issue in docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, microservices, rancher

I use Docker Rancher as a Docker Desktop replacement on **macOS**, everything works fine except host mounting volumes in docker-compose for my Nodejs project. I must ignore the **tests** folder via **.dockerignore** and have the host volume from my local root folder (.) to the container root folder (/app):

**docker-compose.yml**

```
 volumes:
  - .:/app
  - /app/node_modules
```

Seems docker rancher has problem to mounting volumes in macOS.
Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: I'd usually recommend deleting `volumes:` blocks like that, so that you're using the `/app` directory that's built into your image.  You can `brew install nodejs` if you're using Homebrew to get a working Node environment on your host for local development and unit testing.

Comment: Have you tried switching volume type to `9p`? Others have had success here https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/issues/1209#issuecomment-1370181132.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I did it. Followed the link that you shared. But still is not working.

Comment: Hi @user1445018 did you managed to resolved this issue? I also have same issue